# How to use unbound keys as “non-sticky” modifier keys

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to setup keyboard shortcuts with other keys that traditional modifier keys, as modifier keys.

example : bind `"f1-left"` ( so <kbd>F1</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>) to a command.

But not bind the sequence <kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> to the command like explained in this answer :
[Using function keys as "sticky" modifier keys](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34617/using-function-keys-as-sticky-modifier-keys)

is that something possible in emacs ?

I see commands such as

`(define-key function-key-map [f8] 'event-apply-super-modifier)`
but is there a command binding on press and on release events ? like a "define-key-press" "define-key-release" ?
If so we could bind a command `event-apply-super-modifier` when f1 is pressed and `event-release-super-modifier` when f1 is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently cannot do that within Emacs (at least, not without changing Emacs's C code).
We could expose the "press" and "release" events on keyboard keys, but we don't do that so far.

OTOH, you can do it outside of Emacs with `xmodmap` (or its more modern replacement, IIRC it'd be something like `setxkbmap`).

E.g. something like:

```
xmodmap -e 'add mod4 F1'
```

after which you can do

```
(global-set-key [H-left] 'my-favorite-command-for-f1-left)
```

Comment: You might want to mention that `xmodmap` and `setxkbmap` might not be available on all platforms.